# Font Awesome icons for Webix tree nodes

Tags: html, css, tree, webix

[Webix integrates with Font Awesome](http://docs.webix.com/desktop__icon_types.html). But how can Font Awesome icons be used instead of the default folder/file icons in trees to style individual nodes?

Here's what I've tried:

http://webix.com/snippet/52251623

- `template` only works at the tree level
- `$css` keeps the existing folder/file icon
- there is [no `icon` property documented for trees](http://docs.webix.com/api__refs__ui.tree.html), yet setting one does something... it changes the folder icon into a file one, when the node has children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For single tree it will be like next

```
webix.ui({
  view:"tree",
  type:{
    folder:function(obj){
      if (obj.$count)
        return "<span class='webix_icon fa-folder'></span>";
      return  "<span class='webix_icon fa-file'></span>";
    }
  },
  data:tree_data
})
```

You can check the sample here - http://webix.com/snippet/0f3d85c3

If you want to share this behavior among multiple tree controls, you can define the custom type once

```
webix.type(webix.ui.tree, {
  name:"awesome",
  folder:function(obj){
      if (obj.$count)
        return "<span class='webix_icon fa-folder'></span>";
      return  "<span class='webix_icon fa-file'></span>";
    }
});
```

and later use type:"awesome" to apply the styling

```
webix.ui({
  view:"tree",
  type:"awesome",
  data:tree_data
})
```

Example - http://webix.com/snippet/79dbe741